# ACCESSフォーム内のテキストボックスに値を設定したい

Tags: c#, .net

c#と.Netのuiautomationを使用してACCESSフォーム内のテキストボックスに値を設定したいと考えております。
ACCESSのフォーム外のテキストボックスであればCONTL.type.EditからValuePatternのsetValueできましたが、
フォームに対してはInvaidOperationExeptionが発生してしまいます。
なにか解決作はありますでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Office製品のフォームはWindowsの標準コントロールを使わずに独自の実装をしていたはずです。したがってWindows標準コントロールや.NETフレームワークで作られたアプリケーションをターゲットとして設計されているUIAutomationからの制御は難しいのではないかと思います。

Comment: そうでしたか。EditではなくPaneのほうであれば一応入力できましたけれど、各テキストボックスに直接設定出来るわけではなく、SendKeysを併用しないといけないので面倒ですね。ありがとうございました。

Comment: この質問は既に解決しましたので終了します。

Comment: 解決に至った情報を分かる範囲で構いませんので「自己回答」で残して頂けると、同じ問題に困った人がいた場合の助けになると思います。

Comment: meta に、「質問を終了したくなった場合」についての投稿を行いましたので、よろしければご参照ください。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2634/754

Comment: コメント有難うございます。質問を終了する理由を記載して新たに回答致します

Answer (score 1):

この質問はコメントにより実現が難しいと判明したため、質問を終了します。

当該コメント:

> Office製品のフォームはWindowsの標準コントロールを使わずに独自の実装をしていたはずです。したがってWindo‌​ws標準コントロールや.NETフレームワ‌​ークで作られたアプリケーションをターゲッ‌​トとして設計されているUIAutomat‌​ionからの制御は難しいのではないかと思‌​います。 -- [Kunihiro Narita](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/12774/kunihiro-narita)  17年1月23日 0:45